# What should I know before I start using a Media Foundation Transform?

Tags: c#, mono, ms-media-foundation

I would like to use the [H264 Video Encoder Media Foundation Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) within my program since it seems to be the only library I can find for encoding H264 that is reasonably priced and non-LGPL licensed

Few Questions:
Which versions of windows do these work on?  What if I use Mono? Can I get it to work on Linux?

Also, any licensing restrictions on using them?

Anything else I need to know before using them?

Edit: I've spent a few hours looking around online, I'm just having trouble finding this information and would love to hear from someone with experience.

Comment: I did use google, I spent a few hours on google trying to find this stuff.  I didn't find anything whatsoever regarding Mono, which I assume must mean no.  Also I found one place that said that they worked on Windows vista and after, and another that said they only worked on windows 7 and 8. And I do not see anything regarding licensing, and while I assume it is safe to use commercially, I'd like to see it in writing.  I really did spend time researching this and don't appreciate the down-votes and that comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Foundation is a native COM/Win32 API. You will not use be able to use it on Linux/Mono.

Answer (score 0):

H264 Media Foundation video encoder works on Windows seven and later.

You can't use MediaFoundation on Linux (see post above).

About licensing. If you sell applications with H264 encoder, you have to pay royalties. Go to MPEGLA for more information : [MPEGLA](http://www.mpegla.com/main/default.aspx)